# Unexpected output when trying to print user input through arrays

Tags: c

This code takes in user input into an array and then prints it. Every time I print the user input a random extra character is printed at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char arr[100]; 
    char c;
    printf("Enter a Sentence:");
    int i =0;
    for (i = 0;(c = getchar()) != '\n';++i)
        arr[i] = c;
    arr[++i] = '\n';
    for (int i = 0;arr[i] != '\n';++i)
        putchar(arr[i]);
}
```

For example I expected the output of

```
Enter a sentence:abc
```

to be `abc` but instead I got `abcu`.

Comment: Unneeded include: `#include <ctype.h>`.

Comment: 1) the posted code has no limit on the number of characters that the user can enter.  This is a potential error.  2) the posted code fails to output the final '\n' so the data will not be actually output until after the program ends

Comment: You should use type `int` for `c`, not type `char`.  That's the type returned by `getchar`, and you will not be able to properly distinguish an `EOF` value if you cast the result to `char` before checking for it.

Comment: This is another example of why the *preincrement* operator (e.g. `++i`) should be avoided in favor of the *postincrement* operator `i++`.

Comment: This code should not compile. You're defining `i` twice: `int i =0;` and `for (int i = 0;arr[i] != '\n';++i)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
arr[++i] = '\n'; /* this skips the current a[i] & put \n into next position which is incorrect */
```

to

```
arr[i] = '\n';
```

as the variable `i` already incremented in condition part of `for` loop here

```
for (i = 0;(c = getchar()) != '\n';++i /* before loop terminating i incremented here */) {
     arr[i] = c;
 }
```

Also its good to initialize the buffer while declaring itself to avoid getting some junk value. For e.g

```
char arr[100] = {}; /* zerod whole array */
```

And also make sure  this `(c = getchar()) != '\n'` doesn't happen `>100` times else buffer overflow happens which cause **undefined behavior**. One possible way is

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)-1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n';++i) {
     arr[i] = c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
for (i = 0;(c = getchar()) != '\n';++i)
    arr[i] = c;
arr[++i] = '\n'; /* here */
```

should be this:

```
for (i = 0;(c = getchar()) != '\n' && i < 100;++i)
    arr[i] = c;
arr[i] = '\n'; /* here */
```

You're skipping one character of the buffer, as `i` had been incremented already at the end of the previous loop. This reads uninitialized data from the buffer (presumably originating from the stack).

You're also not stopping past the end of the buffer, which could cause buffer overflow.

Along with that, you should probably initialize the array with this:

```
char arr[100] = { '\0' };
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

```
arr[++i] = '\n';
```

This is incrementing `i` before assigning `'\n'`, so `arr[++i]` points an extra character into the array.

That is why an unexpected character is being printed.

If you replace that statement with:

```
arr[i] = '\n';
```

your code should work.

Comment: @JL2210,  There are many ways that the code can be corrected.  So demanding that the OP fix the code a certain way, as your edit is doing, is very misleading.  That is why my (original) answer 'suggested' rather than demanded a specific fix

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: @JL2210:  Yes, That is much better

Answer (score 0):

When you read the newline, `i` has just been increased to 3 by the update expression in the first `for` loop.

Then `arr[++i] = '\n'` increases `i` to 4 and assigns to `arr[4]`. Nothing ever gets assigned to `arr[3]`, but it appears that this location happened to contain an `u` when the array was allocated from the stack.